# CURL UPS API, barebones version

Tags: php, api, curl, ups

**Looking For:** a minimalist bare bones PHP/CURL script to "get a shipping label" from the UPS API server.

**Reason:** many Developer APIs consist of thousands upon thousands of lines of code, 99.999% of which I will never use. Rather than litter my server with directories, files, classes, includes, scripts, etc., I would like to implement a single "from sender, to recipient" PHP script that will always yield a UPS Ground shipping label.

**What it might look like (pseudocode)**

```
$data = array(
'ServiceLevel' => 'UPS GROUND',
'ServiceAccessToken' => 'XXXABCDEFGXXX',
'Username' => 'MYNAME',
'Password' => 'PASSWORD',
'To' => 'John Doe 123 Any Street New York',
'From' => 'Your Mom at 777 Happy Town', etc. etc.
)
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https // UPS-ENDPOINT-LOCATION');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$label_image = $result[shipment][label_image];
echo " < img src=$label_image > ";
?>
```

I have UPS Developer Account credentials, the only thing I don't have is the programming knowhow to reverse-engineer the half-dozen different programming languages to condense down to a few lines of PHP/Curl.

Comment: You pretty much figured it out. What is missing?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to stick the label on the box.

Comment: so what does `echo $result['shipment']['label_image'];` give you?

Comment: @nice_dev, thank you, I am appreciating your humor. I was hoping someone had a barebones working cURL script that would yield a shipping label. And, of course, the code I provided is merely non-working pseudocode to illustrate the minimalilst level of code I was seeking. Hopefully someone, somewhere has written a workable script they would like to share.